# For replacing blank cells in a column

Tags: r

I need to replace blanks cells with "-" in a column which is in numeric structure . I tried using `ifelse ==""; is.na; is.null; trimws(col) ==""; levels()`. Nothing working for me.  Please help!

Comment: Do you want to add more column or only need for select? Because column with numeric value cannot be filled with `-`

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan adding another column also works for me.

Comment: Can you give more info about your dataframe? Or maybe sample? I checked code from @Hilal Ahmad works on me. Maybe it's not really blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming your data frame is named 'df' and the column is 'col'
df$col <- ifelse(is.na(df$col) | df$col == "", "-", df$col)
```

Comment: Hi Hilal, this is not working.